# Having trouble implementing functions. One that can delete an item from the list and one that can update an item in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to put functions into my program that make me able to delete an item from the dictionary and one that can make me able to update the grades for a student in the dictionary.

The commented lines are the sections that I need to fill with code.

The below code is what I have so far:

```
grade_book = {
                203942: [88,78,83],
                236732: [90,78],
            9874: [78],
                29746: [79,90], 
        75893: [82,80], 
        352418: [77,88,84],
        13563: [90,89,92] 
}

while True:
    print('Select 1 to display grades')
    print('Select 2 to add new student grade')
    print('Select 3 to update a student record')
    print('Select 4 to delete a student record')
    key_pressed = input("Selection: ")
    if key_pressed == '1':
        print('{:<15}'.format(', '.join(map(str, ["Students Ids"  , "Grades"]))))
        for key, value in grade_book.items():
            print("{:<15} {:<15}".format(key, ', '.join(map(str, value))))
            pass
    elif key_pressed == '2':
        id = input('Enter new student id: ')
        grades = input('Enter the grades: ')

        grade_book[id] = [int(grade) for grade in grades.split(',')]
    #elif key_pressed == '3':


    #elif key_pressed == '4':


    elif key_pressed == '5':
        break
    else:
        print('Error!',key_pressed, 'is not a valid value')

print('Program Ended!')
```

Heres the sample output when you enter '3' (the input indicating you want to update a students grades):

```
Selection: 3

Which student do you want to update?    
1 - 203942
2 - 236732
3 - 9874
4 - 29746 
5 - 75893 
6 - 352418
7 - 13563 
Selection: 3 

Enter the grades for the student separated by commas: 93,77,62
Updated Successfully!
```

For this I am confused at how to get the dictionary listed out like that and how to get an input from the user to choose one of the values given

Next, here is the sample output when '4' (the input indicating you want to delete a student from the grade book):

```
Which student do you want to delete?
1 - 203942
2 - 236732
3 - 9874
4 - 29746 
5 - 75893 
6 - 352418
7 - 13563 
Selection: 2
Deleted successfully!
```

Again, I am confused at how to get the items in the dictionary listed out like this and how to get a user inputted number

I appreciate any and all help. If you need me to elaborate more please ask. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does update mean you append new grades or replace existing grades of a student?

Comment: replace the existing grades

Answer (score 0):

The following adds features 3 & 4 to your code.

**Code**

```
grade_book = {
                203942: [88,78,83],
                236732: [90,78],
            9874: [78],
                29746: [79,90], 
        75893: [82,80], 
        352418: [77,88,84],
        13563: [90,89,92] 
}

while True:
    print('Select 1 to display grades')
    print('Select 2 to add new student grade')
    print('Select 3 to update a student record')
    print('Select 4 to delete a student record')
    key_pressed = input("Selection: ")
    if key_pressed == '1':
        print('{:<15}'.format(', '.join(map(str, ["Students Ids"  , "Grades"]))))
        for key, value in grade_book.items():
            print("{:<15} {:<15}".format(key, ', '.join(map(str, value))))
            pass
    elif key_pressed == '2':
        id = input('Enter new student id: ')
        grades = input('Enter the grades: ')

        grade_book[id] = [int(grade) for grade in grades.split(',')]
    elif key_pressed == '3':
      print('Which student do you want to update? ')
      print(*grade_book.keys(), sep='\n')
      student_id = input('Selection: ')
      if student_id.isdigit() and int(student_id) in grade_book:
        student_id = int(student_id)
        grades = input('Enter the grades for the student separated by commas: ')
        grades = list(map(int, grades.split(','))) # alternative to  [int(grade) for grade in grades.split(',')]
        grade_book.update({student_id: grades})
      else:
        print('Student not in grade book')

    elif key_pressed == '4':
      print('Which student do you want to delete? ')
      print(*grade_book.keys(), sep='\n')
      student_id = input('Selection: ')
      if student_id.isdigit() and int(student_id) in grade_book:
        student_id = int(student_id)
        del grade_book[student_id]
        print('Deleted successfully!')
    else:
        print('Student not in grade book')

    elif key_pressed == '5':
        break
    else:
        print('Error!',key_pressed, 'is not a valid value')

print('Program Ended!')
```

**Explanation**

You mention you were unsure of:

1. how to get the list of student ids.
2. how to delete an item from a dictionary
3. how to update a dictionary

For 1, to get a list of students ids:

```
print(*grade_book.keys(), sep='\n')
```

- grade_book.keys() - is a list of all student ids
- *grade_book.keys() - passes print each id as a separate parameter (list unpacking)
- sep = '\n' - places a  between each
  parameter in print

For 2, [several options to delete dictionary key](https://thispointer.com/different-ways-to-remove-a-key-from-dictionary-in-python/) but I used:

```
del grade_book[student_id]
```

For 3, several options to [update dictionary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update) but I used:

```
grade_book.update({student_id: grades})
```

Another option would have been:

```
grade_book[student_id] = grades
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly. I believe you want to know how to remove dictionary items and/or list items. The standard command for this is called pop.

```
d = dict(thing=5,x=3,y=7)
print(d)
d.pop('thing')
print(d)

l = list('abcde')
print(l)
l.pop(2)
print(l)
```

The pop() function is essentially the delete function. The pop() function also returns the value, in case you wanted to use value that you just deleted.